# How to find $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $c = \frac{(a+b)(a+b+1)}{2} + b$ for a given $c\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Suppsoe that $$c = \frac{(a+b)(a+b+1)}{2} + b$$

Now $c$ is given - how does one find satisfying $a, b$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: You can set $d=a+b$ and solve the resulting equation $d^2+3d-2(a+c)=0$ in $d$. This gives a dependency $d(a)$ and hence $b(a)$.

Comment: Presumably, $a,b,c$ are natural numbers.

Comment: @NickKidman Where did the $3$ come from?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: $\frac{d(d+1)}{2}+d+x=\frac{3}{2}d+y$.

Comment: I've edited the title to reflect the domain where $a,b,c$ belong. As you question is tagged as "number-theory", I think, as Thomas Andrews suggests, you mean $a,b,c$ are natural numbers. Please roll back if I am wrong.

Comment: Ah, hadn't noted the $b$ at the end became an $a$. Yeah, you can just have kept $d^2+d-2(c-b)$. @NickKidman

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the condition that $a,b,c$ are natural numbers.

Let $T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ be the $n$th triangular number.

Let $T_m$ be the largest triangular number less than or equal to $c$.

Show that $c-T_m\leq m$

Let $a=c-T_m$ and $b=m-a$.

You can actually get an explicit formula for $m$, namely:
$$m=\left\lfloor \frac{-1+\sqrt{8c+1}}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 0):

the equation:

$c=\frac{(a+b)(a+b+1)}{2}+b$

Solutions can be written:

$a=\frac{q(q\pm1)}{2}-c-1$

$b=c-\frac{q(q\mp1)}{2}$

$q$ - what some integer.