# Unique Integer solution of a non-linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, diophantine-equations

How to find the integer solution of the equation

$$\frac{m^2 + 2mn + n^2 -3m -n+2}{2}=2$$

I know that there is a unique solution

Comment: There are only two possible complex values of $m+n$ that satisfy the equation.  Why do you tag this with (linear-algebra)?

Comment: Ignore the previous comment.  I put an extra 3 in the numerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there are infinitely many integer solutions, though only one in positive integers.

Write $s=m+n,d=m-n$ then your problem can be rewritten as
$$
d=(s-1)^2-3
$$
We can choose any value for $s$ and get a solution, e.g.
$$
(m,n) = (-1,1),(-1,2),(0,2),(2,1),(5,-1),(9,-4),\ldots
$$
If we want to constrain $m>0,n>0$ then that gives us the constraints
$$
s>0, \quad d\le s-2, \quad d\ge 2-s
$$
which leaves only one solution.

Answer (score 3):

By inspection, $m=2$, $n=1$.

**Remark:** For more information, look for the Cantor Pairing Function. There are explicit expressions for the two "unpairing" functions that recover the first and second coordinates from the result when the pairing function has been applied to $(m,n)$.

Comment: Umm, those values do not solve the stated equation.  I get that there are no possible integer solutions, as $m + n$ is irrational.  Error in equation?  Have I made a stupid mistake?

Comment: Oops.  Indeed, I was making *two* stupid mistakes.  Sorry!

Comment: @ André Nicolas : yes, I just formulated the map from $N XN$ to $N$ for Cantor Pairing function. I am asking whether it is possible to solve with some standard method ?

Comment: Look at the "undoing" functions in the Wikipedia article. You will have to modify a little. Nothing fancier than square root and integer part is involved.

Answer (score 0):

equation:

$\frac{m^2+2mn+n^2-3m-n+2}{2}=2$

Has the solutions:

$n=2-\frac{k(k\mp1)}{2}$

$m=\frac{k(k\pm1)}{2}-1$

$k$ - any integer.