# $a,b \in \mathbb N $ , $b$ odd $\implies$ $ \dfrac{2a^2-1}{b^2+2} \notin \mathbb Z $?

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b$ are positive integers and $b$ is odd , then is it ever possible that $ \dfrac{2a^2-1}{b^2+2} $ is an integer ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $b$ is odd, $b^2 + 2\equiv 3\pmod{8}$. Thus $2$ is not a quadratic residue mod $(b^2 + 2)$. Hence $2a^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{b^2 + 2}$, from which the result follows.

Comment: You want to work modulo $8$, note that for example $2$ is a QR of $7$.

Comment: Oops, yes, thanks: (2/b) depends on b mod 8, not 4.

Comment: In principle the QR business has to do with primes. So one really should say that $b^2+2$ has a prime divisor $p$ of the form $8k\pm 3$. Then work modulo $p$.

Comment: Er, why was this (now year-old) answer voted down?

Comment: Someone may want to have the question deleted, because OP did not "show work." That is something I do not approve of, since it can serve to deprive the site of interesting questions and/or answers.

Comment: ...but a year after the original post?

Answer (score -1):

Can this formula to use.
[How to solve an equation of the form $ax^2 - by^2 + cx - dy + e =0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526164/how-to-solve-an-equation-of-the-form-ax2-by2-cx-dy-e-0/829148#829148)
But we'll see this topic and select the desired formula.
[Families of curves over number fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346546/families-of-curves-over-number-fields/838043#838043)

Comment: It is difficult to substitute in the formula and check if the root be whole? Why formulas do not like?