# integral point on conics

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, algebraic-curves

Suppose we have a conic $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Is there a way of computing the *integer* points on this curve. Since it is affine an not projective we can't just find the rational points and clear denominators.

Thanks

Comment: This is at least as hard as solving Pell's equations (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation). Note that it's equivalent to require $a, b, c, d, e, f \in \mathbb{Z}$ after clearing denominators.

Comment: Constantly this question appears.  Look there or in my answers.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526164/how-to-solve-an-equation-of-the-form-ax2-by2-cx-dy-e-0/829148#829148   If formulas little will look in the blog.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?u=206450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

April 2017: if, in the letters named in the question, we have
$$ a=c=0, $$
see, among many such questions,
[How to solve Diophantine equations of the form $Axy + Bx + Cy + D = N$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258800/how-to-solve-diophantine-equations-of-the-form-axy-bx-cy-d-n)

Oh, forgot, as Qiaochu says, integers.

Took me a while; never bothered to write out the general case before, but it came out alright. In any case, you can check what I wrote against a multiple of what you wrote, see if i got it all correct.

Define $$ \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c  $$

Then you are solving
$$ \left( \Delta y + bd -2ae\right)^2 - \Delta  \left(2ax+by+d \right)^2 =    \left(bd -2ae \right)^2  - \Delta   \left(d^2 - 4 a f \right)   $$
where the final quantity, $ \left(d^2 - 4 a f \right),$ is not squared. As you can see, there is a solution when $f=0$ with $x,y = 0.$

If $ \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c  $ is negative, there are, at most, finitely many solutions. If $ \Delta$ is zero or a positive square, the left hand side factors and there are finitely many solutions, if any.  If $ \Delta$ is positive and not a square, there is a Pell type equation, if there are any solutions there are infinitely many. Finding all of them is a mess unless the right hand side has very small absolute value. Even then you need that subset of the Pell-like solutions that allow integer values of $x,y.$

Comment: Actually, unless I am very confused, this does not work. Consider the hyperbola $$ y = \frac{a x + b}{c x + d}.$$ The good news is that $\Delta$ is a perfect square. The **bad** news is that the equation seemingly educes to $0=0.$

Comment: @Igor  I did that one a few minutes ago, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258280/whats-the-best-strategy-for-finding-the-integers-solutions-of-an-hyperbola/2258313#2258313  I am not 100 percent sure, it is certainly possible that the answer above fails for square $\Delta.$ I do not think I even considered that at the time.

Comment: @Igor I guess I will look at it tomorrow with $\Delta = \delta^2$ and a  third case with $\Delta = 0,$ if I get anything I like edit it in.

Comment: I might be making an arithmetic error (the OP of the question you mention had also posted it on the mathematica board, obnoxiously, and that was why I was looking at it). I found your old answer, but it seems to reduce to $0=0$ using your method here.

Comment: @Igor done what I intended. Taking either $a=0$ or $c=0$ or both. The missing case is a parabola, when $\Delta = 0$ but at least one of $a,b,c$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

April 2017. There has been some interest for the case with some coefficients $0.$  I decided to write it with $c=0.$

IF $c=0,$ so that
$$a  x^2 + b  x  y  + d  x + e  y + f = 0, $$

THEN
$$ ( a  b  x + b^2  y + b  d - a  e )  (  b  x + e) = - b^2 f - a e^2 + bde.  $$
The right hand side is an integer constant, all its divisors, positive and negative, can be found. For each divisor $$ t |  (- b^2 f - a e^2 + bde), $$
solve
$$ bx + e = t,  $$
$$ a  b  x + b^2  y + b  d - a  e = \frac{- b^2 f - a e^2 + bde}{t}, $$
and make sure that both $x,y$ come out as integers.

===========================================================================

IF we take instead $a=0,$ so that
$$ b  x  y  + c y^2+ d  x + e  y + f = 0, $$

THEN
$$ ( b^2  x + b c  y + b  e - cd )  (  b  y + d) = - b^2 f - c d^2 + bde.  $$

===========================================================================

IF we have both $a=c=0,$ 
$$ b  x  y  +  d  x + e  y + f = 0, $$

THEN
$$ ( bx+e )  (  b  y + d) = - b f + de,  $$
where we see we got to erase one factor of $b$ throughout.

===========================================================================

Comment: Excellent! These things ARE a bit pesky...