# For which $a,b,c$ is the diophantine quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=y^2$ soluble?

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics, decision-problems

Given $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, consider the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=y^2$. Are there any general methods for deciding whether this equation has any integer solutions for $x,y$, given the coefficients?

Comment: Please provide more context to the question, also show what you know (special cases) and what you don't. A good point to start is of course https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation ... it includes a discussion on some sligtly more general case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell's_equation

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526164/how-to-solve-an-equation-of-the-form-ax2-by2-cx-dy-e-0/829148#829148

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219___2
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216__

Comment: $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%3Dy%5E2+over+integers)

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $x$ to get $$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac+4ay^2}}{2a}$$ so you need $b^2-4ac+4ay^2$ to be a square, lets say $b^2-4ac+4ay^2 = z^2$.

If $a$ is negative it's easy to see that you need only a finite search. That's also the case if $a$ is a square.

The remaining cases are studied under the name of [generalized Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell%27s_equation)